# How to set Oracle bind variables when using SQLPlus?

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

How do I set Oracle bind variables when using SQLPlus?

Example:

```
SELECT orders.order_no FROM orders WHERE orders.order_date BETWEEN :v1 AND :v2
```

How do I set the dates of `:v1` and `:v2`?

Comment: You can define it as `SQL>define v1=2` and later can use as `SQL>select * from emp where Id=&v1`.

Comment: [The documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_five.htm#i1211850) can help

Answer (score 7):

Notice the following:

- VARIABLE is a SQLPlus command. You don't end it with a semicolon (;).
- In the VARIABLE command, you do not precede the variable name with
  colon (:).
- Bind variable can't be of data type "date" - they are some sort of
  character value.
- For that reason, IN YOUR CODE you must use `to_date()` with the
  proper format model, or some other mechanism, to convert string to
  date. That is currently missing in your code. NEVER compare dates to
  strings!

Brief demo below.

```
SQL> variable v1 varchar2(20)

SQL> exec :v1 := '2015/12/22';
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select 1 as result from dual where to_date(:v1, 'yyyy/mm/dd') < sysdate;

    RESULT
----------
         1
```

Answer (score 2):

In common 
you may use **define** and use variable with &

```
define x = 12 ;
select &x from dual;
```

Or **varable**

```
variable x refcursor;
begin
 open :x for select * from dual connect by level < 11;
end;
/
print x
```

Comment: The OP asked specifically about bind variables - which are much better than substitution variables. And he/she asked about using them in a straight SQL query; what's with `refcursor` and such?

Comment: The OP asked "How do I set Oracle variables when using SQLPlus?" Where you find word bind? And for his question I add two variants of solution. Am I wrong?

Comment: In the code and in the question - notice the colon before the names of the variables? `:v1` is a bind variable, there can be no confusion about that.

Comment: Looking at the question again, it could be made clearer by adding the word "bind" in a few places. I'll edit it in a minute to do just that.

Answer (score 0):

since [12.2](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqpug/VARIABLE.html) you don't need pl/sql to set the bind variable, set it direct in the VARIABLE command and save your shared pool:

```
SQL> variable s varchar2(10) = 'myString'
SQL> select :s from dual;

:S
--------------------------------
myString

SQL> variable s = 'anotherStr';
SQL> select :s from dual;

:S
--------------------------------
anotherStr

SQL>
```

BR