# bind variable substitution in oracle sql string

Tags: sql, plsql, tablespace, bind-variables

I am trying to get the default dbf file location from a select statement and use this location to create tablespaces later on. I am having some trouble doing it in the sql script. I tried to use pl/sql and bind variables. Please let me know how i could fix this. Thanks

```
VARIABLE v_name VARCHAR2;
BEGIN
 select value into :v_name from v$parameter where name = 'db_create_file_dest';
END;
/

CREATE TABLESPACE cyyou_test DATAFILE  :v_name||'/test.dbf' SIZE 100M .....;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set Oracle bind variables when using SQLPlus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39993497/how-to-set-oracle-bind-variables-when-using-sqlplus)

Comment: Why are you trying to explicitly set the location of the datafile, if you have DB_CREATE_FILE_DEST set?  The entire purpose of this parameter is to tell Oracle where to put datafiles automatically.

Comment: You can't use bind variables in DDL statements. If this is a SQL\*Plus script you could use substitution variables.

Comment: I realized that I do not need explicitly set the location of the datafile.